# Python - parse a line of text

Tags: python, parsing, loops, readfile

I have the following input from a text file:

```
Title Value Position Perturbation 1.5 0.6 8.5 9.8 0 8.5 9.6 0.5 0.6 (...)

Title Value Position Perturbation 3 1.5 6 0 0.8 9.7 5.3 9.9 0.7 0.9 (...)
```

I want to remove the first 4 columns and for the columns with numbers I want to subset every 4 values and changing the position of the 3rd value for the second one and remove the fourth one, so, the output should look like:

```
1.5 8.5 0.6 0 9.6 8.5 0.6 (...)
3 6 1.5 0.8 5.3 9.7 0.7 (...)
```

For this propose I write the following Python code:

```
import sys

input_file= open (sys.argv[1],'r')
output_file= open (sys.argv[2], 'w')
with open(sys.argv[1]) as input_file:
for i, line in enumerate(input_file):
        output_file.write ('\n')
        marker_info= line.split()
        #snp= marker_info[0]
        end= len(marker_info)   
        x=4
        y=8
        # while y<=len(marker_info):
        while x<=end:
            intensities= marker_info[x:y]
            AA= intensities[0]
            BB= intensities[1]
            AB= intensities[2]
            NN= intensities[3]
            output_file.write ('%s' '\t' '%s' '\t' '%s' '\t' % (AA, AB, BB))
            x= y 
            y= x + 4
input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

The code seems to work fine but the problem is that for each line, the last four values are missing. So, I guess that the problem is in the "while" statement...But I have not clue how to solve it (I know that it seems a simple problem).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Just FYI: When using with resources you don't need to manually close the input stream. That's the reason why there is "with" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, its all based on your script, except at while expression and open file method.
Input File :

```
Title Value Position Perturbation 1.5 0.6 8.5 9.8 0 8.5 9.6 0.5 0.6 1.1 2.2 3.3
Title Value Position Perturbation 3 1.5 6 0 0.8 9.7 5.3 9.9 0.7 0.9 1.1 2.2
Title Value Position Perturbation 3.1 2.5 1.6 0 1.8 2.7 4.3 6.9 3.7 1.9 2.1 3.2
```

Script :

```
with open("parser.txt", "r") as input_file, open("output_parser.txt","w") as output_file:
    for i, line in enumerate(input_file):
        output_file.write ('\n')
        marker_info= line.split()
        end= len(marker_info)
        x=4
        y=8

        while y<=end: #x<=end:
            intensities= marker_info[x:y]
            AA= intensities[0]
            BB= intensities[1]
            AB= intensities[2]
            NN= intensities[3]
            output_file.write ('%s' '\t' '%s' '\t' '%s' '\t' % (AA, AB, BB))
            print end, x, y, marker_info[x:y], AA, AB, BB

            x= y 
            y= x + 4
```

Output :

```
1.5 8.5 0.6 0   9.6 8.5 0.6 2.2 1.1 
3   6   1.5 0.8 5.3 9.7 0.7 1.1 0.9 
3.1 1.6 2.5 1.8 4.3 2.7 3.7 2.1 1.9
```

Comment: I test your Py code, but I get an error on print:  https://snipboard.io/8fiPHJ.jpg  you should put round brackets after the print

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Open file like csv and strip the labels 

2. Generate a sublist of desired size

3. Do your swap and remove the trailing element

4. Save the output (i've done it with a list, but you can do it with output file)

```
>>> import csv
>>> output = []
>>> with open('sample.csv') as input:
...     reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter=' ')
...     for line in reader:
...         line = line[4:] #strip labels
...         slice_size = 4
...         for slice_idx in range(0,len(line),slice_size):
...             sublist = line[slice_idx : slice_idx+slice_size]
...             if len(sublist) == slice_size:
...                 swap = sublist[2]
...                 sublist[2] = sublist[1]
...                 sublist[1] = swap
...                 output.append(sublist[:slice_size-1])
... 
>>> 
>>> output
[['1.5', '8.5', '0.6'], ['0', '9.6', '8.5'], ['3', '6', '1.5'], ['0.8', '5.3', '9.7']]
```

Comment: slice_size = 4
                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: the script is well indented, could you do a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I get the previous error but no more info about it. Anyway, do you have any clue where the error is in my code? Just to understand where the mistake is and be able to improve my coding skills.

Comment: the error says that your code isn't well indented, so you should check  that lines are together and they respect the spaces before the code

Comment: Done, but more debugging: sublist[2] = sublist[1] TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: I already solved the problem. It is a big file and some lines contained and error. Thanks for your time.